# Joomla expensive tag queries on homepage

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, tags

I noticed insane amount of queries on homepage for `XXX_contentitem_tag_map`. I actually don't display tags on homepage, since I've 100 articles on homepage - selecting tags for each article slows everything down considerably.

I noticed in `ContentModelArticles` class, method `getItems`

[image]

I need to disable this everywhere except on article page where I actually display tags.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that all 100 articles displayed in one page? In a blog format? Or just a link?

Comment: @webchun 1 page yes, blog format - link excerpt + thumb.

Comment: Do you use a module to display them or by creating a category Blog menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we removed tags queries from this model and J seems to be working just fine and faster.